# Does a torus action with isolated fixed points imply rational?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry

Suppose that $X$ is a smooth projective variety $/\mathbb{C}$ with a $\mathbb{C}^{*}$-action with isolated fixed points. Must $X$ be rational?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes. This follows from the Białynicki-Birula decomposition (see Theorem 4.4 in [the original paper](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1970915)).